# Componente anidado no se muestra en ruta

Tags: reactjs

Estoy creando un e-commerce, el problema comienza en **routes.js**

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router,  Switch,  Route} from "react-router-dom";
import { NavBar } from './components/navBar/navBar';
import {HomePage} from './components/screens/HomePage/HomePage';
import {ProductPage} from './components/screens/ProductPage/ProductPage';
import {Cart} from './components/screens/ShoppingCart/ShoppingCart';


const Routes = () => {

return (
<Router>
    <main className="routes">
         <NavBar />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/">
                  <HomePage/>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/product/:id">
                  <ProductPage/>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/cart">
                  <Cart/>
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </main>
</Router>
);
}

export default Routes
```

Los objetos *HomePage* y *ProductPage* funcionan, se ven en la pagina. EL problema es en el objeto
*Cart*, importado desde **ShoppingCart.js**

```
 import './ShoppingCart.css';
 import CartItem from '../../cart/cartItem';

 export const Cart = () => {
   return (
        <div className="shoppingcart">
            <div className="shoppingcart_left">
                <h2>Tu carrito</h2>

                <CartItem />
            </div>
            <div className="shoppingcart_right">

            </div>
        </div>
)
}
```

No solo no aparece el titulo de "Mi carrito" y el objeto *CartItem*, sino que tampoco esta el NavBar. Al que pueda responder, desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la versión de react-router?

Comment: la version de react-router-dom es 5.3.0 me instale esa version porque aun no me adapte a la mas reciente. No creo que sea eso porque ande mal, tengo otra creada el año pasado que aun me funciona

Comment: Bien, lo que yo haría enseguida es `console.log(Cart)`en Routes para verificar si estoy trayendo el componente, y tambien intentaría configurar la ruta asi `<Route path="/cart" component={Cart} />`

Comment: escribiendo component me fue lo mismo y el código... me salio el codigo

Comment: pareciera que funciona @g.4

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo descubrí el problema... me olvide de ponerle el return al **CartItem**, y por eso la pagina se había colapsado